# Count same lists in a list

Tags: python, list

```
list1 =[ ['9034968', 'ETH'], ['14160113', 'ETH'], ['9034968', 'ETH'], ['11111', 'NOT'], ['9555269', 'NOT'], ['15724032', 'ETH'], ['15481740', 'ETH'], ['15481757', 'ETH'], ['15481724', 'ETH'], ['10307528', 'ETH'], ['15481757', 'ETH'], ['15481724', 'ETH'], ['15481740', 'ETH'], ['15379365', 'ETH'], ['11111', 'NOT'], ['9555269', 'NOT'], ['15379365', 'ETH']
```

How do I count the same lists in a list. For example here:
`['9034968', 'ETH']` appears 2 times, so does `['15481740', 'ETH']`. I am currently able to do it using:

```
>>> for i in list1: 
      i, list1.count(i)
```

But this returns duplicate results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Counter`,

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(tuple(i) for i in list1)
```

converting to `tuple` makes your items *hashable* for the `Counter`

You can do stuffs like:

```
counter.most_common(3) # get the 3 most common items
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get unique items in the list by making the elements tuples and converting it to a set:

```
for i in set(map(tuple, list1)): 
    i, list1.count(i)
```

Better yet, use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (see Moses Koledoye's answer).